# Change defined arguments in inherited view in backbone.js

Tags: inheritance, backbone.js

I'm going to inherit a view the following way

```
define('view1', ['backbone', 'jquery', 'subview1'], function(Backbone, $, subview1){
    var view1 = Backbone.View.extend({
        initialize: function() {
            //some code with subview1
        },
        function1: function(){
            //some code with subview1
        }
    });
    return view1;
}
```

and the child view

```
define('view2', ['backbone', 'jquery', 'view1', 'subview2'], function(Backbone, $, view1, subview2){
    var view2 = view1.extend({
        initialize: function(e) {
            view1.prototype.initialize.apply(this, [e]);
        }
    });
    return view2;
}
```

Can I somehow use subview2 instead of subview1 in the child view or it's necessary to rewrite all functions where it's used manually? One important thing, **view1** cannot be changed because provided as a third party library.

Comment: What is the third party library? Some libraries (eg. marionette) have this type of functionality built in.

Comment: It's a custom view from the customer that should be reused on my side

Comment: Probably out of luck then. I was thinking if it was an open source library, that they would have built it with extensibility in mind. If it is a custom view built by someone else, then they probably didn't build it that way.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest thing to do would be to build `view1` with extensibility in mind. If you store the subview in the prototype:

```
var view1 = Backbone.View.extend({
    //...
    subview: subview1
});
```

then `view1` can refer to `this.subview` instead of `subview1` and subclasses can override the `subview` property through the prototype:

```
var view2 = view1.extend({
    //...
    subview: subview2
});
```

and everything will work as expected.

For example: https://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/ra52ssm4/

Comment: It's a nice and simple way, thanks, but I'm not allowed to change view1, the question was updated.

Comment: If you can't change `view1` to be subclassable then I think you're out of luck.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the factory method pattern. You would separate the code to create the subView into a method, then just override that method in the subclass. Then you shouldn't have to duplicate your other logic.

```
var SubView1 = Backbone.View.extend({
  render: function() {
    this.$el.html('<h1>SubView 1</h1>');
    return this;
  }
});

var SubView2 = Backbone.View.extend({
  render: function() {
    this.$el.html('<h1>SubView 2</h1>');
    return this;
  }
});

var View1 = Backbone.View.extend({
  render: function() {
    var view = this.createSubView();
    this.$el.append(view.render().el);

    return this;
  },

  createSubView: function() {
    return new SubView1();
  }
});

var View2 = View1.extend({
  createSubView: function() {
    return new SubView2();
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, It's a good way but I don't have access to change view1, the question was updated.

Comment: I like your approach, you should add a response to the TOs new requirements and mention your current apporach as option to workaround this from the beginning. (+1 is rewarded then)